# confusion in usage of "as for myself"

Tags: sentence-construction, phrase-meaning, phrase-usage, phrase-choice

I'm confused with the usage of **as for myself**. Whether it is used to tell something about our personal life or to tell our opinion/thinking?

Consider this:

> **As for myself**, I was always a self-occupied person and that's why I hate being invited to social gatherings.

> **As for myself**, I think money matters a lot in life, and we should not underestimate the power of wealth in life.

> **As for myself**, I believe in ghosts and paranormal from my childhood.

Do these sentences sound natural? I sometimes think that as for myself is redundant with I think and I believe. However, it is considered a C2 level grammar structure by Cambridge.

Comment: ***Why*** do you want to introduce a statement about yourself with the words ***As for myself***? Semantically, it's exactly equivalent to, for example, ***[speaking] personally***, but this doesn't really mean anything unless you're "countering" some earlier assertion (from someone ***else***) that you ***don't*** agree with. Or at least, you think the current context is such that you don't expect everyone to agree with what ***you*** think.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Reinstate Monica...It's a C2 level grammar structure that is why I want to use it in my writing. Consider this link for reference : http://www.englishprofile.org/component/grammar/content/921

Comment: I assume you realise that in nearly all cases, ***as for myself*** is effectively an almost meaningless "discourse marker" - on a par with saying ***Well...,*** or ***Um...,*** or simply clearing your throat before speaking. Also note that although your link actually says it can be used ***to introduce** or focus on a personal opinion*, it's not suitable for introducing a *conversation* (you'd normally only use it to specifically ***redirect*** the conversational focus onto what ***you*** think, because the current focus is "elsewhere").

Comment: In short, unless you provide some ***full*** "prior context", it makes no sense to ask whether any of your examples are "natural".